# Android Studio crash application

Tags: java, android, crash

I'am totally noob with Android, and just started learning and start one project. Everything was good, but when I want to click button for Register, application crash. I fixed some error, but this can't a long time. 
Try to debbug also, but don't underestand what debugger said. 
Any comment, pls help

```
package com.example.demir.carsharing;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Display;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v){
        if (v.getId()==R.id.bLogin)
        {
            EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFUsername);
            String str = a.getText().toString();

            EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TFPassword);
            String pass = b.getText().toString();

            String password = helper.searchPass(str);

            if(pass.equals(password))
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
                i.putExtra("Username", str);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                // DIsplay popup message
                Toast temp =Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username and Password don't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                temp.show();

            }

        }
        if (v.getId()==R.id.bSignUpHere)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, signup.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is a log file

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.demir.carsharing, PID: 3566
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                   Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.demir.carsharing/com.example.demir.carsharing.signup}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:77)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
                      at com.example.demir.carsharing.MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.java:53)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and do something like this:

```
private Button v;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    v = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignUpHere);
    v.setOnClickListener(SignUpOnClick);


}

View.OnClickListener SignUpOnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, signup.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
};
```

And the error you linked is because you havn't declared the wanted activity in the manifest.

so below the mainActivity add another decleration in manifest.

Like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".signup"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: show me pictures of the errors or explain in more details

Comment: The error is that when I open the tag, cannot close it: I can post the code here.

Comment: OK, I still cannot comment on answers, so I will comment here on your latest answer:

You have delared on two different activites that they are MAIN and LAUNCHER and this means that you two activities to open right on application launch, and this is of course an error.

simply remove the unnecessery 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: I create Splash screen, that's why is it. So when application i start, first it's opet welcom activity which is 4 sec, and after that it's open Login screen.

Comment: Thats Ok, so if that's the case, simply make your splash screen activity the MAIN and LAUNCHER and all the rest delete the intent-filter part from them.

Comment: Yeah, now work. Thank you man a lot :)

Comment: Awesome, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demir.carsharing">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".Welcome">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".TripRegistration"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```